# Google maps getTag() is always null even though setTag() is not

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow

I am trying to add a tag via marker.setTag(Object object) in the addMarkers method below. I have debugged to ensure that there is no null in the value being set in the tag. However, when I try to retrieve the tag data via getTag(), I am getting null and I have no idea why and what I am going wrong.

```
private void addMarkers() {
        resetMap();
        CollectionReference restaurantCollection = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Restaurant_Data");
        restaurantCollection.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    GeoPoint restaurantPoints = documentSnapshot.getGeoPoint("geoPoint");
                    String restaurantName = documentSnapshot.getString("restaurantName");
                    String snippet = documentSnapshot.getString("restaurantDescription");
                    double lat = restaurantPoints.getLatitude();
                    double lng = restaurantPoints.getLongitude();
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    if (googleMap != null) {
                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(restaurantName).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(162)).snippet(snippet);
                        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                        RestaurantMarker restaurantMarker = new RestaurantMarker(documentSnapshot.getId(), marker);
                        markerRestaurantIdArrayList.add(restaurantMarker);
                        marker.setTag(restaurantMarker);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the method where I am retrieving the tag. I know that the marker is not only not null but is also the correct one since I am getting the correct latlng/placement on the map along with title and snippet:

```
@Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(final Marker marker) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mapviewContext);
        builder.setMessage(marker.getSnippet()).setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("See Menu", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                RestaurantMarker restaurantMarker = (RestaurantMarker)marker.getTag();
                if (restaurantMarker != null && marker.getTag() instanceof RestaurantMarker) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "restaurant ID:"+ restaurantMarker.getRestaurantId());
                    bundle.putString("restaurantId", restaurantMarker.getRestaurantId());
                    bundle.putString("restaurantName", marker.getTitle());
                    bundle.putBoolean("direction", true);
                    restaurantMapListener.onRestaurantMap(bundle);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "restaurant marker is null");
                }
                dialogInterface.cancel();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Calculate Distance", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                resetSelectedMarker();
                selectedMarker = marker;
                calculateDirections(marker);
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                markerRestaurantName = marker.getTitle();
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

And finally here is the RestaurantMaker POJO. No issues here either because I am using it elsewhere and without any issues:

```
public class RestaurantMarker {
    public String restaurantId;
    public Marker restaurantMarker;

    public RestaurantMarker(String restaurantId, Marker restaurantMarker) {
        this.restaurantId = restaurantId;
        this.restaurantMarker = restaurantMarker;
    }

    public String getRestaurantId() {
        return restaurantId;
    }

    public void setRestaurantId(String restaurantId) {
        this.restaurantId = restaurantId;
    }

    public Marker getRestaurantMarker() {
        return restaurantMarker;
    }

    public void setRestaurantMarker(Marker restaurantMarker) {
        this.restaurantMarker = restaurantMarker;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code of `addMarkers()`:

> ```
> ...
> MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(restaurantName).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(162)).snippet(snippet);
> googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
> Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
> RestaurantMarker restaurantMarker = new RestaurantMarker(documentSnapshot.getId(), marker);
> markerRestaurantIdArrayList.add(restaurantMarker);
> marker.setTag(restaurantMarker);
> ...
> ```

you add marker to `googleMap` twice (on same `LatLng` position): once at `googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);` line, then at `Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);` line, but set tag only for "second time added" marker. Probably when you try to retrieve the tag data via `getTag()` for clicked marker it called on "first time added" marker with no tag set (because both of markers has same `LatLng` coordinates). So, try to remove `googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);` line from `addMarkers()` method:

```
...
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(restaurantName).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(162)).snippet(snippet);
//googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);  <-- delete this line
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
RestaurantMarker restaurantMarker = new RestaurantMarker(documentSnapshot.getId(), marker);
markerRestaurantIdArrayList.add(restaurantMarker);
marker.setTag(restaurantMarker);
...
```

Comment: You are right. There was a flaw in my understanding. I thought by assigning the marker it would not be placed on the map; which is why I was adding it to the map and then assigning it to the marker variable. Thanks.